# VBA Changing font color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, fonts

[image]

| S.No | Topic | Priority | Action | From | Date | Responsible | Target | Done | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FuSi | 3 | kjkj | SSR0 | 26.07.2022 | MR.BBBB | 18.08.2022 |  | kjkjkj |
| 2 | FuSi | 3 | kjkj | SSR0 | 26.07.2022 | MR.BBBB |  | 19.08.2022 | kjkjkj |

simple task. I wanted to know if anyone could help me out? I’ve got a excel sheet with the columns Target (H) and Done (I).

I want the code to do 2 things:

1. If the date in the column H is overdue the entire row should change the font color to orange.
2. If there is a date in column I the entire  row should change its color to green.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Do you mean the excel Table ?

Comment: Not the whole table, just a few rows, but **not as a screenshot** but as text, such that someone can easily copy/paste it in Excel and verify their answer.

Comment: Yes, doesn't need to be real, just examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: okay i am trying to figure out how to paste the Information of the Table into my question

Comment: do you definitely need VBA, or conditional formatting could be ok too?

Comment: Ideally it should be able to run automagically i don't know if conditional formatting does . that is why i thought of vba.

Comment: the table i inserted helps to check with your solutions :)

Comment: @bastoshenrique93 very kind of you to format it as a table,! Next time you could consider posting the comma or tab separated values in a code block, that is often simpler to get from your Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting is enough - you don't need the complexity of VBA.

You need to create two rules on the same rows, one changing the row to red
and the other to green.

Here is a theoretical example (untested) :

- Select the entire dataset (A2:Gsomething).
- Click the Home tab
- In the Styles group, click on Conditional Formatting
- Click on ‘New Rules’
- In the ‘New Formatting Rule’ dialog box, click on
  ‘Use a formula to determine which cells to format’
- In the formula field, enter the formula
  `=AND($H2>TODAY();$I2="")`.
  The other formula could be `$I2<>""`
- Click the ‘Format’ button
- In the dialog box that opens, set the color
- Click OK.

[image]

For more information with screenshots see for example the article
[Highlight Rows Based on a Cell Value in Excel (Conditional Formatting)](https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-rows-based-on-cell-value/).

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a try :)

Comment: hey sorry for only testing it today, but when i put in the formula i get an error message saying that whenever i start a formula with a "=" or "-" excel expects a formula.

Comment: I tested and it works. You have to pay attention to : If your separator is comma (`,`) rather than `;` and if Excel hasn't added too many double-quotes (`"`) when pasting the formula.

Comment: It was the language i had to write it in German but somehow, it changes the font only if the date is in the future. when i change the" >" to "<"  all lines without any date change their colour.

Comment: It should work. I don't have a German Excel and can't duplicate the problem.

Comment: it does work the only problem are the blanks I can't find a way to leave them out. i tried "=ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE" but it didn't work

Comment: ISBLANK is the same as comparing with `""`. Or does the cell contain blank characters?

Comment: Yes my Problem is That Not every Cell in the column H has a target date. If there is no date it shouldn’t change the font color.

Comment: Wherever my formula above contained `$I2`, replace it by `TRIM($I2)`.

Comment: Sorry I think I didn’t explain it right. There are cells without any target date . These cells are beeing considered smaller than today. I want them to stay with the white font.

Comment: But you should be testing for greater-than today.

Comment: than its changes for dates in the future and it should change dates which are overdue

Comment: Its working now, i had to add ;$H2<>””

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).